# Hello,We are sending a PDF attachment through mail in VB.NET.But one column is displaying '#####' instead of some value

Tags: vb.net, pdf

We are sending a PDF attachment through mail in VB.NET.But one column is displaying '#####' instead of some value.We have increased the column width.But it is causing problem for Some users for others its working fine.Can anybody know the solution please guide.Any PDF setting needs to be changed?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is creating the PDF file? Does it show '#####' before it is attached to the email?

Comment: After sending the mail user can open the PDF file.In that file all the values are visible but only for one column #### is coming

Comment: How is the PDF file created?

Comment: Created xl file and converting to PDF

Comment: oWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat(Excel.XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF, PDFFile, Excel.XlFixedFormatQuality.xlQualityMinimum, _
                                                          pIncludeDocProperties, _
                                                          pIgnorePrintAreas, _
                                                          pFrom, pTo, pOpenAfterPublish)

Comment: If you look at the data that should be shown in the cell, is there anything wrong with it? For example, it could contain some text that is longer than it should be.

Comment: The legth of the value to be displayed is 12 digits.And in program also the width is 25(MonExcel.Columns("D:D").ColumnWidth = 25).Its a integer value

Comment: If you save one of the problem Excel files to disk as an Excel file (in addition to saving it as a PDF) and look at it, is there anything strange?